# How to reuse a bound port with OpenSSL api?

Tags: openssl, port, reusability

I'm writing a Server with OpenSSL API. I want to reuse the port that is already in use.

I can do so in socket programming by calling

```
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
```

before I call

```
bind(sockfd, ...);
```

But how to reuse the port in **OpenSSL programming**?

I use

```
bio = BIO_new_ssl(ctx, 0);
BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
abio = BIO_new_accept(server_port);
BIO_set_accept_bios(abio, bio);
BIO_do_accept(abio)
```

to setup my OpenSSL Server connection.

Are there any functions such as `setsockopt()` can make a `BIO *` reuse the port?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `BIO_set_bind_mode`:

```
BIO_set_bind_mode(abio, BIO_BIND_REUSEADDR);
```

Comment: @Celebi: You can't, because you have to call it on the accept `BIO` itself, which is created by `BIO_new_accept()`.  You can call it anytime between when the accept `BIO` has been created and the first `BIO_do_accept()` call.